# Connection to database - MySQL

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, database-connection

I have a problem to connect to database. I just had this problem few days ago when I started using Mac instead of Dell. The connection is still working on Dell. I'm using Eclipse, Tomcat server, MySQL. This is what I have displayed on my console.

[image]

I hope this will be helpful:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the password is root? I thought by default the username is root but the password is just blank? Could be wrong though, but just a suggestion!

Comment: @ReeceKenney, I tried both, with and without "root".

Comment: Right after `System.out.println("Erreur de connexion!");`, you should add `e.printStackTrace()`, it'll show you more info about the problem. Also, it's a bad idea to put Java code in a JSP. You should move towards a MVC style approach.

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()`, or at least `System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());` instead of `System.out.println("your arbitrary message");`. The you can see, what the problem is.

Comment: I used System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage()); and this is what I get: Error:Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using a non standard port number for MYSQL so this command will need to reflect that non standard port number.

I am a little rusty on Java but try this

```
String dataServiceURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/majjane";
```

Possibly using a ip rather than `localhost` would also help, it woudl probably make it faster if nothing else.

```
String dataServiceURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/majjane";
```

Comment: My bad! I was using more than one connection in the same page, and when I tried the solution you suggested I did it only for one connection! But it's working now, I added the port for all the connections. I'm just wondering, is it normal to have the exception even if the Try block is working?

Comment: Yes, what if the database has crashed, or some clever or maybe not so clever clogs moves the database or changes the non standard port number back to the normal 3306 port? etc etc etc _Try catch is for life, not just for christmas_

Comment: I just tried the port 3306, it's not working on it. It's working only on 8889. It won't affect the database or something like that if I continue to use it even if I have an exception, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If MYSQL is listening on port 8889 then leave your code using `:8889`